# How do I find the length of the polar spiral $r = a\cdot \theta^2 - 1 + b\cdot \theta$?

Tags: graphing-functions

> How do I find the length of this polar spiral?
>
> $$r = a\cdot \theta^2 - 1 + b\cdot \theta,$$ where $a$ and $b$ are variables.

Comment: Do you know a formula for arc length using polar coordinates?

Comment: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/integral-calculus/ic-adv-funcs/dc-polar-arc-length/v/polar-arc-length-formula

Answer (score 1):

The formula tells us ( assuming $\;0\le\theta\le2\pi\;$ )

$$\mathcal L=\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{r^2+r_\theta^2} \,d\theta=\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{(a\theta^2+b\theta-1)^2+(2a\theta+b)^2}\,d\theta$$

Not the nicest integral to see...but give it a try.

Pay attention to the fact that

$$r_\theta^2=\left(\frac{dr}{d\theta}\right)^2$$

Comment: I've no idea. I haven't even tried to solve that integral: it looks nasty. Yet you can try to do it with Wolfram or some other program...

Comment: @user33915 I'm sorry but I still have no idea, yet this time it is because I can't understand what you mean: why the integral changes and all?? And how come you want to integrate with the **variable** ($\,\theta\,$) being fixed?